# What is a gvec4?

Tags: opengl

As mentioned here, https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/imageLoad.xhtml, there is supposed to exist a gvec4-type. But i can't find anything about it. What is that datatype?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The term `gvec4` is used as a catch-all for all vector types: floats, signed integers, unsigned integers, and doubles. The "g" is replaced in the actual type by:

- Nothing, for `float`s. (`vec4`)
- `i` for signed ints. (`ivec4`)
- `u` for unsigned ints. (`uvec4`)
- `d` for `double`s. (`dvec4`)

In this case, `imageLoad` will return different vector types based on the type of the image. The "g" in the image type will match the "g" in the return type. Floating-point image types (like `image2d`) make `imageLoad` return `vec4`. Signed integer image types (like `iimage2d`) make `imageLoad` return `ivec4`. And so on.